# WordPress - Security Risk?

Tags: security, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and the following link is accessible: `www.domain.com/wp-admin/` (obviously not the real domain name). Someone told me that this is a security risk. Any truth to this?

Comment: Better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In essence, the more information an attacker has about your setup, the worse off you are.

That being said, however, the information gained by knowing your admin login page is pretty trivial - as it's the default login location for all WordPress sites.  Therefore, once an attacker figured out your site was a WordPress site, he/she would naturally try that link.

As long as you keep your WordPress files up to date, the only thing you're really vulnerable (that you would be protected from if that page was inaccessible) to is an 0day on that specific page...

So, really, it doesn't matter much either way.  Personally, I would deny access to that as much as was convenient - but, on the other hand, you may like having that link always open so you can login and admin your site from anywhere.  I dare say you'll be fine either way, so long as you have sufficiently strong passwords.

Update:  Another thing to consider, the login pages of (well-written, tested)open-source software are rarely ever the point of failure for authentication attacks.  Usually, compromising a system involves disclosure of credentials using another vulnerable page, and then using the login page as it was intended to be used.  The WordPress devs have combed over the code in your login page because they know it's going to be the first place that anybody looks for an exploit. I would be more concerned about any extensions you're running than leaving the login page viewable by the public.

Comment: I've noticed you're asking about specific security risks of leaving it open: Bruteforcing this type of login takes too long to be useful, and you'd notice it in your logs, so you could simply take action to block an IP.  I think WP might by default force a cooldown of a few minutes if you try and login too many times in a row, so you're fine there.  Adding an .htaccess entry to stop general access is another layer, and when it comes to security, layers are _always_ good.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply Wordpress. Nothing inherently wrong with it. But if you are concerned overall with security, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress and http://www.reaper-x.com/2007/09/01/hardening-wordpress-with-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess/ and http://www.whoishostingthis.com/blog/2010/05/24/hardening-wordpress/  etc., on protecting admin with .htaccess, removing some WP identifiable clues, changing the database prefix, SSL access, and on and on. Some things are more worthwhile to do than others, some more obscurity than security, but it's all a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Well a lot of sites have open wp-admin , however you can put in a .htaccess file and password protect the directory, provided you are on apache.

Comment: I am on Apache. This link suggest the same thing as you are suggesting: http://netaccountant.net/blogs-blogging-for-accountants/how-to-secure-your-wordpress-wp-admin-folder/. I wonder though: what exactly is the security risk here? And how dangerous is this risk?

Comment: well its you blog admin , so if someone really wants to get it they can try to brute force etc and get access to your administration panel. So any security you can implement is a good idea unless you don't really have any data that you are worried about in there :)

Answer (score 0):

it's not a big deal... there's a lot of stuff to avoid it being there... you could even have your whole wp install in a subdirectory of the server

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to know what is the security risk of having this accessible to the public. Any ideas???

Comment: the onlyone I can think of is that knowing you're WP powered could lead to having a "malicious user" look for a way to exploit WP powered websites. I mean, there's more important security concerns in a wp install than the wp-login route...for instance don't just leave the default "admin" user..change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for WordPress, but I know at least two e-commerce softwares (Zen Cart and PrestaShop) recommending to rename the admin directory to some other name (and not to print the URL in orders...).
Perhaps there are some known exploits using this information...

Comment: Security by obscurity isn't security at all.

Comment: Sure, I would prefer maintainers of the projects to fix the security holes instead, as there are so many ways to leak the information anyway. Hey, I haven't invented the advice to hide this folder! And the question is, basically, "why rename it?", so I just give an answer. But somehow, a password is security by obscurity too, and can be leaked as well...